# Java Executor Service Start Threads when Application Launches

Tags: java, executorservice, java-threads

When my application launches, a executor service (using Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreadNum) in java.util.concurrent) object is created. When requests come, the executor service will creates threads to handle them.

Because it takes time to create threads at run time, I want to make threads available when launching application, so that when requests come, it would take less time to process.

What I did is following:

```
executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(200);
for (int i=0; i<200; i++) {
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Start thread in pool " );
        }
    });
}
```

It will creates 200 threads in the executorService pool when application launches.

Just wonder is this a correct way of creating threads when application starts?
Or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: This is correct and that is the exact reason why Thread Pools are invented. To eliminate the creation delay of threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) directly rather than an `ExecutorService` from `Executors`<sup>1</sup>, then there's perhaps a more standard/supported way to start all the core threads immediately.

```
int nThreads = 200;
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads, 
        0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
executor.prestartAllCoreThreads();
```

The above uses [`prestartAllCoreThreads()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#prestartAllCoreThreads()).

Note that, currently, the implementation of `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)` creates a `ThreadPoolExecutor` in the exact same manner as above. This means you could technically cast the `ExecutorService` returned by the factory method to a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. There's nothing in the documentation that *guarantees* it will be a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, however.

---

<sup>1. `ThreadPoolExecutor` implements `ExecutorService` but provides more functionality. Also, many of the factory methods in `Executors` either returns a `ThreadPoolExecutor` directly or a wrapper that delegates to one. Some, like `newWorkStealingPool`, use the `ForkJoinPool`. Again, the return types of these factory methods are implementation details so don't rely too much on it.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `shutdown()`.It is very important to shutdown the Executor service once the operation is completed. So have `try,catch and Finally block`

`try{
    executorService.execute(...);
 }catach(Exception e){
   ...
 }finally{
   executorService.shutdown(); //Mandatory
 }`

Comment: That's not what OP is asking.

Comment: well he is asking whether his implementation is right or not.. also shutdown is necessary else the threads keep running in the background. It wont shutdown immediately.

Comment: You’re right, but that should be posted as a comment. Answers are expected to answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! Will use the try, catch, finally block for exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The number of threads which could run parallel depends on your processor core. Unless you have 200 cores it would be pretty useless to make a thread pool of 200.

A great way to find out how many processors cores you have is:

```
int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

Moreover the overhead which develops during creating a new thread and executing it is unavoidable, so unless the task is heavily computed it would not be worth to create a new single thread for this task.

But after all your code is total fine so far.

Comment: "Unless you have 200 cores it would be pretty useless to make a thread pool of 200" - not true if the threads are doing I/O.

Comment: Really? I did not know about that. Thank you

Comment: My desktop is 8 cores, not sure how many are there for the test server. The number was given by my colleagues before, will discuss with them on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is totally fine if it works for your scenario. Since we don't know your use case, only you can answer your question with enough tests and benchmark.

<s>However, do take note that the ThreadPool will reclaim idle threads after some time. That may bite you if you don't pay attention to it.</s>

Comment: Thank you! Will take note that normal threadpool(if not FixedThreadPool) will reclaim idle threads after some time!

Comment: Sorry, that may not be true. Specifically, only the CachedThreadPool will reclaim idle threads after 60 seconds

Answer (score 0):

> Just wonder is this a correct way of creating threads when application
>   starts?

Yes. That's a correct way of creating threads.

> Or is there a better way of doing it?

Maybe. Under some workloads you might want to use a Thread pool with a variable number of threads (unlike the one created by `newFixedThreadPool`) - one that removes from the pool threads that have been idle for some time.

Comment: it doesn't remove the threads which are idle for sometime- documentation link- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

Comment: That’s what I wrote - the fixed pool doesn’t do that. Some other pools do.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help! The use of FixedThreadPool was designed by my colleagues, will check with them on this.